# Restricting keys in recursively nested Typescript type

Tags: css, typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a recursive Typescript type definition that prevents a parent object with certain keys to have nested children objects with any of those same keys.

For context, I'm playing around with a CSS styling library which I'd like to support strongly-typed 'responsive styles' like this:

```js
const basicResponsive = { height: { xs: 100, sm: 200, md: 300, lg: 400, xl: 500 } }
```

However, it should **not** support objects where the 'responsive' keys are nested, like so:

```js
const invalidNestedResponsive = styleFn({
  xs: {
    height: 100,
    // Should error:
    // Can't nest a responsive style within a responsive style
    xs: {width: 50},
    sm: {width: 51},
    md: {width: 52},
    lg: {width: 53},
    xl: {width: 54},
  },
  sm: {height: 100},
  md: {height: 100},
  lg: {height: 100},
  xl: {height: 100},
})
```

[Here is a Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=42&ssc=1&pln=68&pc=3#code/PQKgUABCEEoKYGcAOB7AdgglgNzhAygC4CeANpmgOYQAqxSikIwEYJDsiqGOcAsgEMkAHhoA+CAF4IAb0gQAHggBctADTyEAW1U0NECFoAmu-RFKVT8haSsBfNvTzxk6LLlETpNCAB9Orjy4giLiYI4cRGRwAGoCpACueJLy-giEAE4UlKkQCWhGcABmFHBGuWgJpKQVCVoARnAZuVGksfFJANoAuuHseACiCgDGiYUu3O5wnlIQQ6MJhcIA1nDEKEXqEKvrmxNuvCHCAmjEYmIReK2IM9L7QdMyEJ07EBRzI2Nw91Oe3ao-XjCa5xRJwCT+a4IGZ2C5gYZuQgQdLRABiaFmngAFCi2qooZ4AJRSCS4uDhUBMCAxACCABkAJIAEQIJDaEAA8vUAFZwYaEBBMFjwxEQeoCLDDWZk9FYp4I0goDKqADkGTKKogdkJ4QRGCRaEQhDKAAUEHBFihpWy4LL5ShFcqIGqNWpncoABYoXAZFWqe2O1X1MEqt1+gT83h+2QQBVK1XEODVFAAd01di1Wp1Iv1YolmGGgNwsyeHrgmEoHsI-sUKggAEYAAyNt3aVQAJmbbuMqgAzF3zJYIAAWAc2VQAVmbmYcOfSECQ5stReSyJtdvkZYrVf9SlUTZbyJ0EE7h57EH7h4sqlHh-HECnjbsZj9Xp90ZkW8r1dke5PA7bEcB3PAA2AdrwgAAOMdbAbZsn2fMBtQpcAoAgBkADlaUZFlrk5Hk+QFIVWD1ecKGweJMCMDCjTKFdrTRNA5WsOs5AMAxgBYfAvSqIwICaDJ43kDiWAAYROFUDSNCABAgdVAimNdoggFNMEID13lk+TJl4JS2mE2t-VUox1MnJ8zAMQCZGM0yH3rRD2MMExZBsj1J3bBz2Ig6yqNside08gx7x8ky3IfYdAogL8dzglt5E8qyDOin8Dws90I0IKN-QMkSCB40g+IEoTHNy8S0EkiBCjgJBSGICBDXnLSuAOYsyRUtSNIxJqFN0skcsMlzfLCqdIss48Qr8+y0oMc8JuGjzpsHIyhsnALFuC1zJwitLPM82bkv3ZtPO8g7Ys84LToPRDkLnJFyMoowGTQQ0Mho9I6Oah4GLaDcDFfb0mg-Ay-zYkrLq7frw0jXAgZK9iQc2h9zP6sbltCszRvY2bEZGxaDG8nHkbhoLYLmjHFsiyLErhhGVqRzGrMJzHsbp3H+oJ1miZKjbOcptL9vLb9Dq5-Gh0-QWYqutKLollKjrMa7CSAA) with what I've tried so far. I tried a bunch of different conditional types, but couldn't quite find one that worked. There are a bunch of test-cases in the playground, as well.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAyqA2EBqBDeBXaBeAUFKAPlAM7ABOAlgHYDmehU6VAJhAGbUTP1FXrzweUPgFsARhDJC4IRKgwQA2gF0cOUJCgAlCMTAB7KsQoA3CAGkIIYlCxQA5AA9i9hveIjXReyOZeH8DT+TvD2eOrg0ACCxABy+jp6hsZmltYAPAAqAHy2UADe9IrmUNRQANZW+mxQmcoAXFAlEI7AECw2iQZGphZWNgD8whBmZFCNmcXKUC1tHVD6YgBWEADGwFAD9JPm07PtzDYoVCAqm7AIyGiY41Ax8V3JvWnEWVO5jTJy1xA4AL5qDTRYhfXRZXJ2Qr4YqlKgVKo1OqNZqtA6dXTdFJ9azne4JDFPVL9N67D7bKYzVHzRYrdbnHZ7KmHKDHU7TIag+Q3RoxUGvBkfC6yK4Kf5qVbJDakYUAMThdiylLmzN5l352WyAAppYgJgBKWy5HW-HBAA) work for you? If so, I'll write it up. If not, let me know the issue. Good luck!

Comment: Amazing, it worked!  Thanks so much 

The generic of the styleFn seemed to matter quite a bit... I had initially tried `const styleFn = <T>(style: AsStyles<T>) => style`, but that was giving incorrect errors. Extending AsStyles<T> instead worked (still not quite sure why, though)

I have one other follow-up question. I tried using an enum for defining the ResponsiveKeys, but it did not seem to work. Do you know why that might be? There seems to be a subtle difference here that might imply that it's not a great use-case for an enum.

Comment: Without seeing your enum I'm not sure, but enum keys and values are different so possibly you're talking about enum values when you really care about enum keys.  Of course if all you care about are the keys then you probably just want a union of string literals instead of an enum.  Again, though, without seeing it I'm just speculating.  I'll write up the answer above when I get a chance